# Jmeter - How to remove id from given json

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I'm comparing 2 jsons with JSR223 Assertion and I'm willing to remove the ids from all levels from the response json:

```
{
  "id" : 52906,
  "name1" : "559812 Company name1",
  "name2" : "559812 Company name2",

  "country" : "DE",
  "interests" : {
    "id" : 848675,
    "description" : false
  },
  "emails" : [ {
    "id" : 904881,
    "address" : "559812@gmail.com"
  } ],
...
```

I'm using the following Groovy code:

```
def slurper2 = new JsonSlurper();
def jsonResponse = slurper2.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
jsonResponse.rows.findAll { it.remove("id") };
```

But it doesn't work - Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand where you got this `rows` bit as I don't see any [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) named "rows" in your response.

If you want to remove **all** "id" attributes you can use the following approach:

```
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
def responseWithoutIds = response.replaceAll("\"id\"[ ]*:[^,}\\]]*[,]?", "")
// do what you need with the modified response, i.e. store it into a JMeter Variable

vars.put("responseWithoutIds", responseWithoutIds)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter replace json attributes]

References:

- [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method JavaDoc
- [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class JavaDoc
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I used the following code:
`
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
    import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
    
    JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper( );
    
    def expected = slurper.parseText( "{\n"
    +"  \"name1\" : \""+vars.get("comp")+" Company name1\",\n"
    +"  \"name2\" : \""+vars.get("comp")+" Company name2\",\n"
    +"  \"emails\" : [ {\n"
    +"    \"address\" : \""+vars.get("comp")+"@gmail.com\"\n"
    +"  } ],\n"
    +"}\n"); '

Comment: def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
    
    def actual = response.replaceAll("\"id\"[ ]*:[^,}\\]]*[,]?", "");
    
    def expected2=new JsonBuilder(expected).toPrettyString();
    
    log.info("ACTUAL = "+actual);
    log.info("EXPECTED = "+expected2);
    
    if (expected2 != actual) {
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    }

The only difference I see in the jsons are the spaces (empty line) (where is the row with the removed id) in the actual. So the comparison results with fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.json.*;
def s='''{
  "id" : 52906,
  "name1" : "559812 Company name1",
  "name2" : "559812 Company name2",

  "country" : "DE",
  "interests" : {
    "id" : 848675,
    "description" : false
  },
  "emails" : [ {
    "id" : 904881,
    "address" : "559812@gmail.com"
  } ]
}
'''

def removeAttr(node, attr){
    if(node instanceof Map){
        node.remove(attr)
        node.each{ k,v-> removeAttr(v, attr) }
    }else if(node instanceof List){
        node.each{ i-> removeAttr(i, attr) }
    }
}

def slurper2 = new JsonSlurper();
def jsonResponse = slurper2.parseText(s);
removeAttr(jsonResponse,"id")

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonResponse))
```